# The keyboard's plists of PressAndHold also can no longer be modified to add the new accents in El Capitan

Tags: keyboard, macos, internationalization

From OS X 10.8 to 10.10, I used to modify the PressAndHold keyboard plists to add the new Romanian and Slavic accents and some symbols, so I'm an hyperglot.

```
/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents
```

From 10.11, they can no longer be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files in /System are protected by System Integrity Protection. If you wish to edit such files, you will need to disable this.

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

<sup>Source: [Disable OS X El Capitan Rootless and permit write actions to System Integrity Protection locations](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)</sup>

You can re-enable it once you've edited the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, software update will soon revert your changes!